# XSL: cannot display datetime

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new in XSL and i try to display a date time.

The information in XML is provided in an attribute :
    date="2013-08-20 00:18:35"

And i would like to display in html page the date with this format :
    20 Aug. 2013 00:18 (or 20/08/2013 00:18)

For moment, i try many things without success...

```
    <xsl:variable name="dt" select="@date" /> //OK
    <xsl:variable name="dtime" select="translate($dt, ' ', 'T')" />  //OK 2013-08-20T00:18:35
    <xsl:variable name="datet" as="xs:dateTime" select="xs:dateTime($dtime)"/>
    <!--
    <xsl:variable name="datet" select="'2011-11-01T12:13:59'"/>
    -->
    <xsl:variable name="finaldate" select="format-dateTime($datet, '[Y0001]/[M01]/[D01]', (), (), ())"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$finaldate" />
```

2 results at this moment :

- no value
- Error during XSLT transformation: An unknown XPath extension function was called.

Any idea ?

Thank you.

---

[Edit]

Here XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="messages.xsl"?>
<AllMessages address="test">
    <messages flag="2" date="2013-08-20 00:18:35" rowid="19120">
        <text>blabla</text>
    </messages>
    <messages flag="3" date="2013-08-20 00:19:58" rowid="19121">
        <text>No pb \u00e7a arrive.</text>
    </messages>
</AllMessages>
```

And XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">
    <!-- <xsl:output method = "html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent = "yes" />-->

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html></xsl:text> -->
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Messages</title>
                <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="messages.css" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="AllMessages/messages">
                    <div id="date">
                        <xsl:variable name="dt" select="@date" />   
                        <xsl:variable name="dtime" select="translate($dt, ' ', 'T')" />                 


                        <xsl:variable name="datet" as="xs:dateTime" select="xs:dateTime($dtime)"/>

                        <!--
                        <xsl:variable name="datet" select="'2011-11-01T12:13:59'"/>
                        -->
                        <xsl:variable name="finaldate" select="format-dateTime($datet, '[D01] [MN,*-3]. [Y0001] [H01]:[m01]', 'fr', (), ())"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$finaldate" />

                        <!-- 
                        <xsl:value-of select="$dtime" /> 
                        -->
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I open the XML with Firefox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An unknown XPath extension function was called

This sounds like you're trying to use an XPath 2.0 expression with a processor that is only capable of XSLT 1.0.  To use the dateTime functions you need a 2.0 processor such as Saxon or Altova XML.

Comment: I just edited my post. I try to use XSLT 2.0 and to generate HTML 5.0 with CSS3 (for border-radius). I have some problems with DOCTYPE, with date format etc.

Comment: @MychaL all browsers I'm aware of are limited to XSLT 1.0 for in-browser transformations triggered by `<?xml-stylesheet?>`.  If you want XSLT 2.0 in the browser you have to use [Saxon CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml)

Comment: hhmmm i try with saxonce. ppfff that was hard for a beginner to succeed to have my page. Now indeed, i have my date formatted but i still have a problem. Here the result: [Language: en]20 AUG. 2013 00:18. Dunno why Language appear specially when i set 'fr' :p

Comment: Saxon-CE currently has no support for any language other than English. If you request an unsupported language, the XSLT 2.0 spec requires the processor to use its default language and add a prefix indicating that it has ignored your request.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply format the date yourself? It's not that difficult to do - even if using XSLT 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:for-each select="AllMessages/messages">
    <div id="date">
    <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
        <xsl:with-param name="date" select="@date"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="formatDate">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:param name="y" select="substring($date, 1, 4 )"/>
    <xsl:param name="m" select="substring($date, 6, 2 )"/>
    <xsl:param name="d" select="substring($date, 9, 3 )"/>
    <xsl:param name="mmm" select="substring('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', 3*($m -1)+1, 3 )"/>
    <xsl:param name="t" select="substring($date, 11, 6 )"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($d, $mmm, '. ', $y, $t)" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

For French month name abbreviations, use:

```
<xsl:param name="mmm" select="normalize-space(substring('jan fév mar avr mai juinjuilaoûtseptoct nov déc', 4*($m -1)+1, 4 ))"/>
```